# Why internal hard-disk is showing twice? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hard-drive

When I run `sudo fdisk -l` command, it's shows my internal hard-disk twice (sda2 & sda5). What could be the reason?. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. Please tell me, if I need to share output of any other command. Thank You in advance.

output of `sudo fdisk -l | grep -A 7 /dev/sd`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 447.14 GiB, 480113590272 bytes, 937721856 sectors
Disk model: Sandisk SD5SB3M2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x36fc1339

--
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 937719807 936667138 446.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 937719807 936667136 446.7G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/loop8: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

--
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.49 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 0741
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x966accd6

--
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953458175 1953456128 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: sda2 is an extended partition (a *logical* partition if you will, it cannot contain any user data, but can be subdivided into other partitions which store the data).  sda5 is the partition created within the space of sda2 that contains actual data.   Key is the word "**extended**" in your first paste.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It does not show your hard disk twice. What you see, are partitions on that drive.

`/dev/sda` is the device name for a classical hard drive. Other drives will be named as `sdb`, `sdc`, etc. Partitions on it are designated with an additional number, e.g. `/dev/sda1` is the device name of the first partition on a drive, `sda2` a second one, etc.

Your disk is partitioned according to the traditional MBR format. On your `sda` hard disk, the Ubuntu installer has created one primary partition, `sda1`, and one extended partition, `sda2`. That extended partition serves to hold additional partitions, known as "logical partitions". In your case, there is a single logical partition `sda5`, which is the partition on which Ubuntu is installed.

The `sda1` partition is an EFI partition formatted with the file system FAT32 as shown in the output (also known as `vfat` in linux). That is a small partition that is used for booting on more modern computers.

So do not worry. All is normal and fine.